# Converting google places details JSON into a C# Object with JavaScriptDeserializer

Tags: c#, json, google-api, google-places-api

I'm currently trying to convert JSON from a google places details api call into a c# object through deserialization. I have successfully done this using the same process for both a google geocode call, and a google places call.

These are my google places, and places details calls:

```
           string uri = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?";

           uri += "key=" + mapkey + "&";
           uri += "location=" + lat.ToString() + "," + lon.ToString() + "&";
           uri += "radius=" + radius.ToString() + "&";
           uri += "types=restaurant";

           string detailUri = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?";

           string results = client.DownloadString(uri);

           JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

           PlacesResponse placesresults = js.Deserialize<PlacesResponse>(results);

           for(int i = 0; i < placesresults.Results.Length; i++ )
           {

               detailUri += "placeid=" + placesresults.Results[i].Place_Id + "&key=" + mapkey;

               string details = client.DownloadString(detailUri);                  

               DetailResponse detailresults = js.Deserialize<DetailResponse>(details);                  

                   restaurants.Add(new Restaurant()
                       {
                           Name = detailresults.Results.Name,
                           PlaceID = detailresults.Results.Name,
                           AddressNumber = detailresults.Results.Name,
                           PhoneNumber = detailresults.Results.Name,
                           Rating = detailresults.Results.Name,
                           WebSite = detailresults.Results.Name
                       });

           }
```

The models I use for google places (working for place ID) are:

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;

   namespace DetroitEatz.Models
   {
       public class PlacesResponse
       {
    public string Status {get;set;}
    public PlacesResults[] Results { get; set; }
   }
   public class PlacesResults
   {
    public PlacesGeometry Geometry { get; set; }
    public string Place_Id { get; set; }

   }
    public class PlacesGeometry
   {
    PlacesLocation Location {get; set;}
   }
    public class PlacesLocation
   {
    public double Lat {get;set;}
    public double Lon {get;set;}
  }

  }
```

The models I use for the details (results null) call are:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace DetroitEatz.Models
 {
    public class DetailResponse
    {
    public string Status {get;set;}
    public DetailResult Results { get; set; }
    }
    public class DetailResult
    {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public double Rating { get; set; }
    public string Formatted_Address { get; set; }
    public string Formatted_Phone_Number { get; set; }
    public DetailAddress_Components[] Adress_Components { get; set; }
    }
    public class DetailAddress_Components
    {
    public string[] Types { get; set; }
    public string Long_Name { get; set; }
    public string Short_Name { get; set; }

    }
    public class DetailGeometry
    {
    public DetailLocation Location { get; set; }
 }
public class DetailLocation
{
    public string Lat {get;set;}
    public string Lon {get;set;}
}
}
```

The problem I am having is that when I deserialize the json string from the details call, the "Results" property is showing up null.

I would really appreciate any help or suggestions to fixing this problem.

Comment: Can you provide a sample `json` that you're receving in `details` and `results`?

Comment: Noticed you answered your own post I found the json2csharp.com site invaluable for getting the consumption of the JSON response right.  BTW in your sample code how are you calling the Google API (are you use WebClient by any chance)?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I fixed the issue using http://json2csharp.com/, in case anyone else has this type of problem. Not positive on the "why", but I suspect it had to either do with the naming convention I had, or me not including every aspect of the results.

Comment: I didn't have much luck with json2csharp.com but found this worked well: http://jsonutils.com/